# How to detect Emoji Unicode?

Tags: java, android, unicode, emoji

I have been using the following library in my android app to add Emoji support

- https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

It contains the class **EmojiconHandler.java** and that the method

```
public static void addEmojis(Context context, Spannable text, int
   emojiSize, int index,    int length)
```

it goes char by char to check the unicode and if emoji unicode has been found it replaces it with the image.

I want to know if there is any alternate way to find unicodes of emojis other than going char by char for the whole text ?

Following unicodes are supported in the code

- http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: can't you only encode the emojis? `String emoji = new String(myEmoji.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: How should it work? If your text is 100 characters long and any character could be an emoji you need to check all 100 characters. There is no other way.